# How to create CSS only bundle in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using a Webpack with `ExtractTextPlugin` to generate a separate CSS bundle. But I do not want Webpack to create any JavaScript files

Comment: That's not possible. Just use a Javascript file that only imports the CSS and ignore the resulting JS file.